# Add values to js script from txt or json file

Tags: javascript

I have basic question regarding adding values to js script. For now I have method `add` to manually add subjects.

```
patientFolder.add({'ID': [subject]}, 'ID', ['1_1', 'G321', '2_1', '11', '20', '21'])
```

I would like to parse .txt file and write it to `patientFolder.add` like this:

patientFolder.add({'ID': [subject]}, 'ID', /tmp/subjects.txt])

content of subjects.txt:

```
1_1
G321
2_1
11
20
21
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Read data from file by following the example
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript/

After this you can split output of file by \n. This will give you an array.
You can pass that array to your patientFolder.add function.

Comment: I get ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined